# Unable to add image in the bg with the background-image property-CSS

Tags: css

I'm using the background-image prop to get an image in the bg and a text on the foreground:
fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/zvy0j3r1/5/

however I dont see any image getting displayed. i'm not sure what I'm I missing here
CSS:

```
.main {
    padding: 40px 70px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%; //customizable user controlled width (not necessarily be 100% all time)
    color: #AFBEC6;
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid #E7ECEE;
    background-color: #F7F8F9;
}

.icon {
    background-image: url(https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/7693/catfront.png);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.text {
      font-size: 24px;
    position: relative;
    top: -18px;
}
```

Comment: position:absolute on icon .. or simply add background to main

Comment: sorry I missed this, but the parent width container is subject to change and hence applying ```position:absolute``` on img breaks when I try to customize the width

Comment: because you need also position:relative of the main

Comment: issue is the `.icon` doesn't a height, therefor you won't see the background, `100%` means `100% of the parent's height` and your parent doesn't have a height

Comment: thanks you everyone for all the tips and guidelines, I was able to get it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the .main as relative and .icons as absolute.

```css
.main {
    padding: 40px 70px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    color: #AFBEC6;
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid #E7ECEE;
    background-color: #F7F8F9;
    position: relative;
}

.icon {
    background-image: url(https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/7693/catfront.png);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.text {
      font-size: 24px;
    position: relative;
    top: -18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="icon"></div>
<div class="text">No Data available</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The background image is not showing because the element doesn't have any height. You might think that using `height: 100%` to the element, would make it take up the same height of it's parent, but it doesn't work like that.

When a child element has `height: 100%`, it will only take up 100% of it's parent if the parent has an explicit height set, like with pixels, ems, vm, etc.